# Where to put try/catch when using IDisposable

Tags: c#, try-catch, idisposable

I was just advised to put an entire `using` block inside a `try`, otherwise the `using` scope will prevent the exception from being caught. However, wouldn't that prevent the `using` from properly disposing its resources if an exception were thrown? If I have the code below, where should I put the `try` blocks?

```
using (connSQL = new SqlConnection(strConn)) 
{
    connSQL.Open();
    using (SqlCommand commSQL = new SqlCommand(strPreparedStatement, connSQL)) 
    {
        if (sqlParameters != null)
        {
            for (int i = sqlParameters.GetLowerBound(0); i <= sqlParameters.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
            {
                commSQL.Parameters.Add(sqlParameters[i]);
            }
        }
        drSQL = commSQL.ExecuteReader();
        dtReturn.Load(drSQL);

        commSQL.Parameters.Clear();
    }
}
```

In this application, it's far more important to ensure connections to the database don't start accumulating due to exceptions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `using` statement will already prevent connections from accumulating - it does the cleanup  side of things for you, by effectively being a `try`/`finally` block with a call to `Dispose` in the `finally` block. If you *also* want a `try`/`catch` block, you can put it either inside or outside - but are you sure it shouldn't be at a higher level? How are you actually expecting to *handle* the exception?

As an aside, it's not clear why you're clearing the parameters from the command when the command is about to be disposed anyway...

I would encourage you to declare the variables within the `using` statements too, so that you don't end up trying to read from them outside the block:

```
using (SqlConnection connSQL = new SqlConnection(strConn)) {
```

In general, prefer to give your variables as narrow a scope as possible. Oh, and your `SqlDataReader` should be in a `using` statement too. It may not matter as you're closing the connection and the command anyway, but I would do it as a point of principle - it implements `IDisposable`, so you should dispose it.

Oh, and your way of iterating over `sqlParameters` is fairly longwinded at the moment. `foreach` makes it simpler, and even if it didn't I'd use `for (int i = 0; i < sqlParameters.Length; i++)` unless I had reason to believe it wasn't a "simple" array.

So, my equivalent code would look something like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strPreparedStatement, connection))
    {
        if (sqlParameters != null)
        {
            // If sqlParameter is an array, you can just use
            // command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameters) instead
            foreach (SqlParameter parameter in sqlParameters)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
        }
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            // Perform any extra initialization here
            table.Load(reader);
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. All very good points. I appreciate the point about `SqlDataReader`. I totally missed that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap the data reader in a using statement as well since it is a disposable resource:

```
using (var connSQL = new SqlConnection(strConn)) 
using (var commSQL = connSQL.CreateCommand()) 
{
    connSQL.Open();
    commSQL.CommandText = strPreparedStatement;
    if (sqlParameters != null)
    {
        for (int i = sqlParameters.GetLowerBound(0); i <= sqlParameters.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            commSQL.Parameters.Add(sqlParameters[i]);
        }
    }
    using (var drSQL = commSQL.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dtReturn.Load(drSQL);
    }
}
```

I have also made the connection, command and data reader objects locally defined into this block scope.

As far as a `try/finally` statement is concerned you no longer need it as the `using` statements ensure that the Dispose method will be invoked even in the event of exceptions. And this method for sql connections and commands ensures to properly release them.

Comment: Good point. I had missed that until the answers here pointed that out. I also prefer using the combined `using` blocks. I'm not sure why I didn't think I could use that here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to put `try` `catch` because `using` implement it implicitly, in fact it uses try finally and sure it will disposes objects.

This is [MSDN using Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) about try catch and using:

```
{
  Font font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
  try
  {
    byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
  }
  finally
  {
    if (font1 != null)
      ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
  }
}
```

is equal to:

```
using (Font font3 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f),
            font4 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f))
{
    // Use font3 and font4.
}
```

Comment: Nitpick - `using` implements try/finally, not try/catch

Comment: Wrong, it wont implement catch. But only try and finally!

Comment: @zenwalker I wrote it implement it implicitly (I mean what the OP wants from try catch) also I said that using do it with try finally.

Comment: when i commented, the rest of your lines were not there. Now you have corrected it!

Comment: @zenwalker yes I wrote it first after that I see it has ambiguity and edit it.