# C# .NET Core - Will a disposable persist across a try/catch block when declared outside? Is this poor practice?

Tags: c#, try-catch, serilog, using, idisposable

Trying to understand best practice here with Serilog context, using statements, and some try/catch blocks. I'm trying to include the Id of some data in the Serilog context when I'm logging anything inside a handful of methods.

All of these methods are surrounded by simple try/catch blocks, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to insert my `using` statement.

This first method feels right to me, as [I know it'll be disposed at the end of the method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using) - but if something errors inside the `try` block, will it still dispose my `ctxId` object? My gut says no, but I can't seem to find an answer.

```cs
[Route("method")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method(Parameters params) { 
  using var ctxId = Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("Id", params.Id.ToString());
  try { 
    // do stuff
    _logger.LogInformation("info...");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.LogError("error...", ex); 
  }
}
```

Ideally, I don't want to have to do something like this (below) and duplicate these lines.

```cs
[Route("method")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Method(Parameters params) { 
  try { 
    // do stuff
    using var ctxId = Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("Id", params.Id.ToString());
    _logger.LogInformation("info...");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    using var ctxId = Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("Id", params.Id.ToString());
    _logger.LogError("error...", ex); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7912316) by Jon Skeet to [Where to put try/catch when using IDisposable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7912294) authoritative enough for you?  It states that a `using` statement *does the cleanup side of things for you, by effectively being a `try/finally` block with a call to `Dispose` in the finally block.*  Or do you want a language reference citation?

Comment: As here we go: from the doc page [using statement - ensure the correct use of disposable objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using): *When the control leaves the block of the `using` statement, an acquired `IDisposable` instance is disposed. **In particular, the `using` statement ensures that a disposable instance is disposed even if an exception occurs within the block of the `using` statement.***

Comment: Will it be disposed? Yes, you can also very easily test that. For example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ilkHAX

Comment: I guess my question is less along the lines of "will it be disposed at all" and more "will it be disposed and therefore inaccessible in the `catch` if there's an error inside the `try`"

From the comments here and the answer below, it seems like it will wait to dispose until the end of the method (outside the try and catch) if I have it configured like the first code block above.

Comment: If you want to know if a variable is accessible at a given location, use it, and see if the code compiles.  If it does, it's accessible, if it doesn't, then it isn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but if something errors inside the try block, will it still dispose my ctxId object?

Yes. `using` is still just "syntactic suggar" for try/finally. So your method be rewritten to something like:

```
ContextId ctxId = null;
try{
  ctxId = Serilog.Context.LogContext.PushProperty("Id", params.Id.ToString());
  try { 
    // do stuff
    _logger.LogInformation("info...");
  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    _logger.LogError("error...", ex); 
  }
}
finally{
    ctxId?.Dispose();
}
```

No matter what happens* in the `//do stuff`, the `ctxId?.Dispose()` will still run. In general, best practice would be to reduce the scope of variables as much as possible.  (Within reason, using to fine scoping can also hurt readability). If that is the entire method, as in your case, then that is perfectly fine.

[ * ] There are some exceptions, like StackOverflowException, that cannot be caught. At that point you have to rely on the OS to do any cleanup.

Comment: I think what I'm asking is the other way around - will my `ctxId` stay usable even through the catch statement? The way I understand Serilog's context, the `Id` context value should stick around until the returned `IDisposable` is disposed. I believe this answers my question though.